# vscode debug python scrapy not step into callback function

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scrapy, vscode-debugger

testing crawler:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "quotes"

def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

and I wrote an main.py:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
execute(["scrapy","crawl","quotes"])
```

and I added python scrapy debugger config, all are fine, until hit
yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
it doesn't step into the callback parse function?

Answer (score 1):

ok, now I know why, because yield request is async, and the callback will be called after the child thread returns the result, so wait a while, it will finally debug into the parse function

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `parse` function is inside class? This code snippet looks like you have wrong indents.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when debugging call back function.

I added `breakpoint()` to callback function, it can debug again. I shared for whom concerned.

```
def parse(self, response):
    breakpoint()
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```